# Registers & Buses

Tags: digital-logic, register

My task is to design a schematic for a register that has an input of clk and i[7:0] which is an 8 bit binary input interpreted as a number and an output of F which goes high if i was equal was to 127 base 10 two rising edges ago, and which is '0' otherwise.  Now I have designed the register having 8 flip flops connected to 8 buses for the input and 8 buses for the output.

How would I go about satisfying the output of F however?  Do I need to attach an AND gate to the output?  How would I show 127 base 10 two rising edges ago?  I am using Xilinx.  Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have the wrong number of registers.  You either need to register everything twice, then make a decision, or make a decision, and register it twice.  Or what is probably the most reliable solution: register the inputs once, make a decision using combinatorial logic operating on the outputs of the input registers, and then register the decision, for a total of two register delays.

Comment: How many registers are needed than?  This is how I had it looking: http://i.stack.imgur.com/FidWG.png

Comment: Depending on the solution chosen, 16, 2 or (8+1)=9.  Technically you could also do it in fan-in stages, such as (4+2)=6 or some other sum.  You seem to have drawn a bank of four flops comprising a 4-bit register, which is not particularly applicable to your problem.

Comment: So I must start from scratch?  Or just add 8 more flip flops?

Comment: You must start by understanding the problem.  Drawing pictures is getting you nowhere.  Ignore the registers for a minute and figure out how to decide if the value is 127, then toss an 8 register on the inputs and a single bit one on the decision output.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is an 8-bit comparator that goes high when both inputs match. The output of this can then be delayed by two clk cycles using i.e. D-FFs. Take a look here: http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/combination/comb_8.html

Comment: 8-bit comparator? or 8-input AND gate?

Comment: You need a comparator (consisting of bitwise 'not XOR' and an AND gate for all the bits). You want the output to be HIGH only if both 8-bit inputs are equal.